# Django: Attempting to create custom 2 password confirmation in my registration form. Form is not valid?

Tags: python, django

my name is Paul, I am an early high school beginner working on my first "independent" project. "Independent" meaning without tutorial guidance. My goal is to make a calendar website, just to keep track of a list of events such as homework, meetings, and such.

Currently, I am working on the registration form. At first, I used the built in UserCreationForm but I decided to create my own HTML form. I am working on recreating this 2 password confirmation form which would take in the two inputs, make sure there aren't any forbidden keys, make sure that the two passwords are matching, and then save that password into the User model's password, along with a username, first_name, and last_name(this would happen in my view.py file).

When I first tried registering, nothing would pop up and as I checked the admin page it turns out no new Users were made. So I put up messages throughout my view if statements to see where the code was getting cut off. It turns out that the form.is_valid was returning false, and I'm not too sure why.

I want to believe it may be that my HTML form inputs do not match my forms.py fields, but I need assistance on fixing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my form.py file.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password']
```

This is the register.html file, the form in which the inputs of the two passwords are. This form is extended to another base template.

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <label for="id_username">Username: </label>
        <div>
            <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="id_first_name">First Name: </label>
        <div>
            <input id="id_first_name" type="text" name="first_name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="id_last_name">Last Name: </label>
        <div>
            <input id="id_last_name" type="text" name="last_name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="id_password1">Password: </label>
        <div>
            <input id="id_password1" type="password" name="password1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="id_password2">Password Confirmation: </label>
        <div>
            <input id="id_password2" type="password" name="password2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
    <div>
        <small>Already Have An Account? <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></small>
    </div>
    {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
    <div role="alert">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

And this is my views.py file, where I am attempting to verify that the two passwords fit the criteria and then save it to the User model.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():
            password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
            password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
            keys = {'a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'e', 'E', 'f', 'F', 'g', 'G', 'h', 'H', 'i', 'I', 'j', 'J',
                    'k', 'K', 'l', 'L', 'm', 'M', 'n', 'N', 'o', 'O', 'p', 'P', 'q', 'Q', 'r', 'R', 's', 'S', 't', 'T',
                    'u', 'U', 'v', 'V', 'w', 'W', 'x', 'X', 'y', 'Y', 'z', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
                    '9', '0', '-', '_', '.'}
            for key in keys:
                if key not in password1:
                    if password1 == password2:
                        form.instance.password = password1
                        form.save()

                        messages.success(request, 'User has been saved.')
                        return redirect('login')
                    else:
                        messages.error(request, 'Passwords do not match.')
                        return redirect('register')
                else:
                    messages.error(request, 'Password contains illegal keys.')
                    return redirect('register')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Form is not valid.')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'request method is not POST.')
        form = UserRegisterForm()

    return render(request, 'User/register.html', {'form': form})
```

At the very last if statement, I'm not sure how to save the password into the form to make a User. Thank you for your time, and absolutely any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to validate and get the password in form.py.

form.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""
New User Form. Requires password confirmation.
"""
password1 = forms.CharField(
    label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput
)
password2 = forms.CharField(
    label='Confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput
)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password']

# to make sure the password and the confirm password are equal
def clean_password2(self):
    # Check that the two password entries match
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
    return password2

# to make sure the added detail of the user in form is saved in database
def save(self, commit=True):
    # Save the provided password in hashed format
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()

    return user
```

view.py

```
def register(request):
form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)

# if the data provided in the form is valid than save the form 
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save(commit=False)
    user = form.save()
    raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')

    user = authenticate(request, email=user.email, password=raw_password)

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
    return redirect('login')

return render(request, 'User/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Hope this gets you some idea on how the password confirmation works.